# Fatest way to retrieve S3 objects metadata (NodeJS API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I stored custom metadatas in my S3 objects (I stored a descriprition of the file in the meta x-amz-metadata-description).

I'd like to retrieve a file list with S3 objects properties, including metadatas.

I thought that `s3.listObjectsV2` can help me but it seems that this method cannot retrieve meta data (see official doc [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property))

I saw that I can retrieve those medata with getObjects, but it will increase a lot the number of call and the latency of the request.

Do you have any idea to bulk retrieve metadatas of a list of objects ?

Thanks,
Romain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need [`aws s3api head-object`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html) which does exactly what you want

> The HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning the object itself. This operation is useful if you're only interested in an object's metadata. To use HEAD, you must have READ access to the object.

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket <mybucket> --key <value>
```

It is also available in nodeJS API, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property

The method is called once per key, if you need to call for multiple items you need to cupple that with other method, lets say as an example you need all metadata for all your csv files from your bucket you would run

```
aws s3 ls --recursive <mybucket> \
| grep ".csv$" | cut -c 32- \
| xargs -I {} aws s3api head-object --bucket <mybucket> --key {}
```

The first part of the command list all files from your bucket, you grep only for a particular extension, strip out characters so you get only the key, and pass this key as argument of the head-object command

Comment: Hi ! thanks. Is it possible to use this method in bulk-mode ? If the answer is no, I will have to perform a lot of calls.

Comment: hi, no you cannot call in bulk, it works for a given key (which makes sense), if you need to call in bulk you first need to select all elements you want to perform the call - giving an example

Answer (score -1):

S3 is not designed for querying objects metadata in bulk. You need to follow answer from @Frédéric Henri if you have less number of files in your bucket, else you need to store metadata in some other datastore like [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), whenever you put a file in the S3 bucket you can [trigger Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) to copy metadata to DynamoDB table and then you can query DynamoDB for metadata in whatever way you desire.